# How to escape a slash while reading an excel

Tags: php, string, escaping

Im reading an excel line by line and doing some php operations in the backend ,but when i reached a cell containing "\" it throwed an error

it has to match the cell value and backend value

cell value `"test-123\/123a"`
backend value `"test123/123a"`

i tried reading the cell value as this `str_replace("\/","/",$cellvalue);`

But error still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try php function stripslashes http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php